# Computing a functor between two categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, derived-functors, functors

I am new to category theory but I think I have a basic understanding of functors.

Is there a way of proving the existence of, and perhaps fully characterizing, a functor $\mathcal{F}$ mapping a category $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. The categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ have undirected graphs as objects and homomorphisms as morphisms. The objects of each category are generated from an initial graph, for instance let us call it $G_0(\mathcal{C})$ for $\mathcal{C}$ and $G_0(\mathcal{D})$ for $\mathcal{D}$.

As an example of how the categories are constructed, let us take $G_0(\mathcal{C})=ACBE$ to be constructed from four nodes $\{A, B, C, E\}$ connected by edges $\{(A, B), (A, E), (B, C)\}$. The morphisms initially map $G_0(\mathcal{C})$ to new homomorphic graphs. In this case, we would get 16 homomorphisms, yielding 16 graphs:

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  AABB$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  AABE$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  ACBB$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  ACBE$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  AAEB$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  AAEE$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  CABB$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  CCBB$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BBAA$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BBAC$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BEAA$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BEAC$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BBCA$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  BBCC$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  EBAA$

$G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  EEAA$

I thought about gluing the redundant nodes together, so that the first graph AABB is formed of nodes $\{A, B\}$, AABE is formed of nodes $\{A, B, E\}$, etc. Similarly, it is possible to continue applying homomorphisms on the second graphs (AABB, AABE, ACBB, etc.) and obtain new ones until all the graphs in one path collapse to one edge $G_0(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow  AABB \rightarrow AB$ (I am not sure if this is true). The whole process will result in a tree-like representation with $G_0(\mathcal{C})$ being the root node and the leafs being final edges (again I am not sure if this is true).

So, for $G_0(\mathcal{C})$ and $G_0(\mathcal{D})$ with $G_0(\mathcal{C}) \neq G_0(\mathcal{D})$, my goal is to compute (or derive?) functor(s) that can map any object or morphism of $\mathcal{C}$ into its corresponding one in $\mathcal{D}$. Of course, such functor(s) have to ensure composition: $\mathcal{F}(f \circ g) = \mathcal{F}f \circ \mathcal{F}g$ with $f,g \in Mor(\mathcal{C})$

Comment: Functors aren't exactly things you _calculate_, usually.  Is there some particular example you're trying to understand?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to characterise the functors that could exist between two categories C and D of undirected graphs. Morphisms are homomorphisms between the objects (graphs) of each category.

Comment: one does not need to calculate functors for these types of problems, if I understand you right. For example, viewing a group as an object with one category, there are no functors $\mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z$, and the set of functors $F:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hi Andres, I don’t understand your example. What I am trying to do is to find mappings between the two categories that preserve the structure. That’s why I thought about using functors since they maintain composition.

Comment: There's no general way to answer this without knowing what categories of graphs you're looking at and what properties you want the functor to have. Except for constant functors, which really don't need much of a description.

Comment: Let me give an example with two categories C and D. Obj(C) are undirected graphs generated from an initial graph Gc. Mor(C) are homomorphisms on Obj(C). Category D has the same type of objects and morphisms but generated from another graph Gd. My goal is to find a functor F: C->D that ensures composition: F(f o g)=Ff o Fg where f and g are homomorphism in C.

Comment: Are you trying to find a functor (assert its existence by construction) or "characterize the functors" as you said previously.

Comment: Could you add some details ? What is a graph generated from an initial graph ? What are the morphisms in $C$ ?

Comment: Andres, Nicholas: I updated my original post with a concrete description of the categories and the problem.

Comment: Can you try to give a better description of the transformations that are allowed on your initial graph to generate new ones? You seem to only mention nodes and it looks like you are gluing nodes together?

Comment: Hi Christoph, I added the full list of allowed homomorphisms for the example. The same procedure should apply to any other undirected graph.

Comment: How does a list like "$AABB$" describe a graph? Is this the original graph with $A$ and $C$ glued together and $B$ and $E$ glued together? Is $AABB$ different from $CCBB$ then? Are the graphs in your category node-labelled?

Comment: Yes that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps, if you think about functors as "*functions between categories*". If you know a bit of linear algebra, one example might be the dualizing functor $(-)^*$, which assigns each vector space its dual vector space.

\begin{align}
(-)^*: \textbf{Vect}_k & \rightarrow \textbf{Vect}_k \\
V &\mapsto V^* = Hom_k(V, k) \\
(\varphi:V \rightarrow W) & \mapsto (\varphi^*: W^*\rightarrow V^*)
\end{align}

$\varphi^*$ is defined by $\varphi^*(f) = f\circ \varphi$, i.e. for $v \in V$ and $f \in W^*$, $\varphi^*(f) (v) = f(\varphi(v))$.

So "calculating" the functor is the same as calculating the dual of a vector space, whenever this is necessary.

Comment: Thank you red_trumpet. My problem is how to translate such construction to undirected graphs (updated in my previous post).